# Conditionally access list of tuples and sum

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have some data that is contained within a list of tuples. I want to sum one part of each tuple if the other part meets a certain set of conditions. Here is some example data:

```
var = [("car", '1'), ("dog", '1'), ("mercedes", '1'), ("cat", '1'), ("ferrari", '1'), ("bird", '1')]
```

I have the following code that will allow me access all the numeric data in the above structure:

```
var = [x[1] for x in var]
print ",".join(map(lambda x: str(x).strip(), var))
```

This will print out data in the following format:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1
```

If I instead used `x[0]` in the list comprehension I would get an output of:

```
car, dog, mercedes, cat, ferrari, bird
```

What I would like to have though is something that says:

```
if x[0] == "car" or x[0] == "mercedes" or x[0] == "ferrari" then var2 == x[1] + x[1] + x[1]
print var2
```

I'm assuming that that above won't work, but I'm not really sure of how to code it in a way that will work.

The above is a simple demonstration. The full string I am parsing is:

```
[("'goal','corner','rightfoot'", '1'), ("'goal','directfreekick','leftfoot'", '1'), 
("'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", '1'), ("'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", '2'), 
("'miss','corner','header'", '3'), ("'miss','directfreekick','leftfoot'", '1'), 
("'miss','directfreekick','rightfoot'", '1'), ("'miss','openplay','header'", '3'), 
("'miss','openplay','leftfoot'", '8'), ("'miss','openplay','rightfoot'", '11')]
```

...and the exact syntax I am using to parse is:

```
matching = {"'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", "'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", "'goal','corner','leftfoot'", "'goal','corner','rightfoot'"}
regex2 = [value for key, value in regex2 if key in matching]
regex2 = sum(int(value) for key, value in regex2 if key in matching)
print regex2
```

...where regex2 is assigned the value of the list of tuples above. The sum line is the one that causes the error. The line above it prints as so:

```
['1', '1', '2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum()` with a generator expression, testing for your conditions:

```
matching = {'car', 'mercedes', 'ferrari'}
sum(int(value) for key, value in var if key in matching)
```

The generator expression does much the same as your list comprehension does; loop over the list and do something with each element. I chose to use tuple assignment in the loop; the two elements in each tuple are assigned to `key` and `value` respectively. We can then filter using an `if` statement (if the `key` value is a member of the `matching` set), and use only the `value` part in the sum.

A quick demo to show you what happens, including a list comprehension version to show you that only a subset of values are picked:

```
>>> var = [("car", '1'), ("dog", '1'), ("mercedes", '1'), ("cat", '1'), ("ferrari", '1'), ("bird", '1')]
>>> matching = {'car', 'mercedes', 'ferrari'}
>>> [value for key, value in var if key in matching]
['1', '1', '1']
>>> sum(int(value) for key, value in var if key in matching)
3
```

Of course, this gets a little more interesting when you use values other than `'1'`:

```
>>> var = [("car", '8'), ("dog", '2'), ("mercedes", '16'), ("cat", '4'), ("ferrari", '32'), ("bird", '64')]
>>> [value for key, value in var if key in matching]
['8', '16', '32']
>>> sum(int(value) for key, value in var if key in matching)
56
```

As for your attempt to implement my solution, you replaced your original list with a list with *only* the values. Remove the list comprehension line rebinding `regex2` and run *just* the `sum()` line:

```
>>> regex2 = [("'goal','corner','rightfoot'", '1'), ("'goal','directfreekick','leftfoot'", '1'), 
... ("'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", '1'), ("'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", '2'), 
... ("'miss','corner','header'", '3'), ("'miss','directfreekick','leftfoot'", '1'), 
... ("'miss','directfreekick','rightfoot'", '1'), ("'miss','openplay','header'", '3'), 
... ("'miss','openplay','leftfoot'", '8'), ("'miss','openplay','rightfoot'", '11')]
>>> matching = {"'goal','openplay','leftfoot'", "'goal','openplay','rightfoot'", "'goal','corner','leftfoot'", "'goal','corner','rightfoot'"}
>>> sum(int(value) for key, value in regex2 if key in matching)
4
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. this looks like it will do what i want it to do, the only complicating factor is the format of the real variables i am using. an example of one of my actual tuples is this (when printed to screen in IDLE): ("'goal','directfreekick','leftfoot'", '1')...so i have tried saying matching = {"'goal','directfreekick','leftfoot'"} however this causes an error saying 'exceptions.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack' which im presuming is because my matching statement is not correct.

Comment: That sounds like you have at least one tuple with just *one* element in it. Your `matching` set definition looks just fine.

Comment: ...ive had a look at them all and they all have two elements in them.

Comment: @user3045351: your exception indicates that the tuple assignment (unpacking) fails *somewhere*. I cannot see how you matched my answer code, nor can I see the full traceback. Does *just* the `[value for key, value in var]` code work for example?

Comment: ...yes that line works, it is the line 'sum(int(value) for key, value in regex2 if key in matching)' that is causing the error. i will edit my answer to show exactly what i am parsing and my syntax used

Comment: @user3045351: but the only unpacking that line executes is the `key, value` iteration target.

Comment: i have edited the question to show exact syntax used.

Comment: @user3045351: you edited my answer instead; I'll reapply your edit to your question.

Comment: @user3045351: you misunderstood my demo; you are summing the output of your list comprehension; that contains *just the one value*; you *replaced* you list of tuples with a list of just the values.

Comment: @user3045351: remove the list comprehension that replaced your `regex2` list with one with just the selected values.

Comment: ok got it, thanks. i thought that was meant to be two separate lines of code rather than two different examples. thanks for all your help.